# Characters and Strings in c with strpbrk

Tags: c, string

Given the followings :

```
char delimiters1[] = {' ' , '&' , '<' , '>'};


char delimiters2[] =  " &<>";
```

If I use the `C` function `strpbrk` with `delimiters1` and `delimiters2` , the results would be the same ?

I've tested both of them with something like 20 inputs , and I got the same output for both .

Am I wrong ?

thanks .

Comment: Did you try with a string that doesn't contain any characters from the set? `delimiters1` and `delimiters2` are not the same, as you can easily see if you do e.g. `sizeof` of both.

Comment: delimiters1 need '\0' end element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char delimiters1[] = {' ' , '&' , '<' , '>'};
```

should be:

```
char delimiters1[] = {' ' , '&' , '<' , '>', 0};
```

It may work few times. But sting should be null-terminated. Otherwise, how will strpbrk will know the end of chars to be searched?

This is the snippet of [strbrk()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk):

```
  while (*s1)
    {
      for (c = s2; *c; c++)
    {
      if (*s1 == *c)
        break;
    }
      if (*c)
    break;
      s1++;
    }
```

Where c is the pointer to the char-set. As you can clearly see that at some point `*c` should be null for the program to work correctly.

Comment: Okay , fair enough  , but is it : `0` or `\0` ?

Comment: `0` or `'\0'`, doesn't matter.

Comment: 0 or '\0' either is just fine.

Comment: Isn't this pointed out by @JoachimPileborg and BLUEPIXY before?

Comment: Does anyone talked about your skills? I'd like to try to be polite, maybe I'm just used to more calm people. Do not tell me you're surprised that many answers are an extended version of a comment of someone else. That said...it's just **etiquette**.

Comment: Life is too short to spend time for this stuffs! I'm sorry if my comment did sound kind of provocation. Usually I **delete** my answer after posting if/when I see someone else gave the same answer before me. Moreover you had my +1 'cause it's the _right_ answer and it's detailed, anyway this kind of debates are for meta, not for SO...

Comment: I think that your answer much kindness  better than one-line comment.

Comment: Technically this answer is right. But I think adding `'\0'` (or `0`) is the wrong thing. If `delimiters1` is a string, initialize it as a string (`" &<>"`). If it's an array of characters, you don't need the null-termination, but don't use functions that expect it.